# Does AVAudioUnitEQ actually work on iOS?

Tags: ios

No matter what I do, I can't get the AVAudioUnitEQ to actually do anything.  If I set the globalGain for the AVAudioUnitEQ, it's definitely effecting the signal, but no matter what kind of EQ filterType I set or parameters, I'm not hearing any change to my sound, it's acting like a straight pass-through.

I've tried low pass, high pass, low shelf, high shelf, setting the gain, the bandwidth, everything I can think of, but nothing seems to make a difference.

Is AVAudioUnitEQ actually functional on iOS 8.4 and 9.1? I'm seeing exactly the same results on iPads with both versions of iOS.

Here's my basic engine setup, trying to get a low pass filter cutting off at 1000 hz.

```
engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];

equalizer = [[AVAudioUnitEQ alloc] initWithNumberOfBands:1];

AVAudioUnitEQFilterParameters *filterParameters = equalizer.bands[0];

filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeLowPass;

filterParameters.frequency = 1000.0f;

equalizer.bypass = NO;  

[engine attachNode:equalizer];

mixer = [[AVAudioEnvironmentNode alloc] init];

[engine attachNode:mixer];
```

AVAudioEnvironmentReverbParameters *reverbParameters = mixer.reverbParameters;

```
reverbParameters.enable = YES;

[reverbParameters loadFactoryReverbPreset:kDefaultReverbType ]; 

[engine connect:mixer to:equalizer format:nil];

[engine connect:equalizer to:[engine mainMixerNode] format:nil];
```

Then later, I connect my various file sources to the mixer and start the engine.  It all works, but I'm just never hearing any EQ happening no matter how I configure the equalizer bands, tried nearly every option I could think of...

Answer (score 6):

Turns out there is an bypass on the individual bands as well as on the equalizer node itself. Setting filterParameters.bypass = NO fixed the problem.